# AngularJS and Ionic for creating windows, android and iOS hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Is it possible to create all 3 app(Windows, iOS and Android) using AngularJS and Ionic. Should I be aware of any pitfalls that might come in at a later stage off development/deployment. Are there any IDE and development style that could make my life easier? If someone could help me in understanding in what i am going to get into it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

sure you can, Ionic is made for this!

you have to know, to build you app on ios, you will need a Mac to compile it.
Same way for windows phone, you need a windows environement to do it.

i suggest you to start with that :

http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

i use Atom to code my ionic applications, but every web text editor or IDEs are ok to code with ionic. It's just a web application, build on HTML and Javascript